# Good HTTP load balancer options

Tags: http

I am looking for a HTTP load balancer with the following features:

1. Dynamic registration of upstream servers over HTTP API - the LB should expose a `/register` API by which upstream servers can register themselves with this LB.
2. Ability to handle sticky session.
3. LB doing health check.
4. URL rewrite.
5. Preferrably out of the box solution, something lightweight.
6. Nice to have: Pluggable strategies, console screen.

I have browsed for Apache Camel but it looked too bulky for my needs. I was also looking at Nginx and it almost ticks all the boxes except #1, I am not sure if it has a way for registration of upstream servers.

Please let me know if there are other interesting stuff out there that I should be looking into.

P.S - In a slightly different context, I was looking at Selenium Grid Hub that does this bit using Jetty internally and its own custom code, which got me thinking this is a generic enough feature that I should be able to use off the shelf.

Comment: Hi, are you looking for URL rewrite in html response bodies or just in back-haul requests?

Comment: Hi @Adrien I am looking for rewrite just in the forwarded requests for now